# Apache Tomcat: how to prevent 404 status during [re]deployment

Tags: tomcat, servlets

When I change the deployment descriptor (e.g. `apache-tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/myApp.xml`) or replace the `myApp.war` file by a new version of my web application, it is stopped and started again using the updated configuration from `myApp.xml` or the new application version from `myApp.war`.

Requests coming in on context path `/myApp` will get a `404` status error page, until the app is fully loaded and enabled to serve requests.

I would like to customize this and present a `503 temporary unavailable` error page instead. Is there a configuration directive for that somewhere?

Workarounds coming to my mind so far include:

- Edit `apache-tomcat/conf/web.xml` and replace `org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet` by custom Servlet implementation responding as desired.
- Or provide a tiny custom web application in `apache-tomcat/webapps/ROOT/` responding as desired.

These are a little bit hacky imho and I hope there's someone knowing a more lightweight solution. I also know about the possibility to deploy multiple versions of the same context path (`myApp##v001.xml`, `myApp##v002.xml`, ...) but having multiple application instances running in parallel is not yet an option.

Comment: If mupltiple app versions is not an option I suspect running two servers is not an option either with a loadbalancer in front. That is what we do and what most people do.

Comment: @Kukeltje We have deployments with IIS->AJP->Tomcat. Can i tell the isapiredirector that a worker is down a minute or two?

Comment: Ohhhh, IIS... hmmmm we have a 'loadbalancing' module in apache http in front of apache tomcat. That module requests an additional basic webapp plain html page (deployed in tomcat) and if it is not present (not responding at all or returning 404) or returns a 'false'/0  then it removes this server from the cluster and only the other(s) are used. If we vhange it again to contain true/1 it starts using this server again. Will ask our network guys name of the module. There might be some similar thing for IIS

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing a little servlet that is deployed as `ROOT.war` and checks for a given request if there is an unavailable (=stopped) deployment with matching context path. If so, a 503 status is returned, 404 otherwise.

In order to access foreign deployments the app depends on `tomcat-catalina` in addition to servlet api:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcatVersion}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcatVersion}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And it must be privileged via `context.xml`:

```
<Context privileged="true"/>
```

This is the servlet mapped to `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`:

```
package my.pkg;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.catalina.Container;
import org.apache.catalina.ContainerServlet;
import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.Host;
import org.apache.catalina.Wrapper;

public class DefaultErrorPageServlet extends HttpServlet implements ContainerServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Host host;
    private Wrapper wrapper;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (matchesForeignUnavailableContextPath(req)) {
            // 503 if there is an unavailabe deployment matching the request
            sendUnavailable(resp);
        } else {
            // 404 if there is no unavailabe deployment matching the request
            sendNotFound(resp);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Redirect to make the client GET the requested URL
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
        final String requestUrl = req.getRequestURL().toString();
        resp.addHeader("Location", requestUrl);
    }

    private boolean matchesForeignUnavailableContextPath(HttpServletRequest req) {
        if (null != host) {
            Container[] children = host.findChildren();
            for (Container container : children) {
                String contextName = container.getName();
                Context context = (Context) host.findChild(contextName);
                if (null != context && !contextName.isEmpty()) {
                    String contextPath = context.getPath();
                    boolean started = context.getState().isAvailable();
                    String requestUri = req.getRequestURI();
                    if (!started && requestUri.startsWith(contextPath)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void sendNotFound(HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
        resp.getWriter().append(
            // HTML document to show on 404 not found
        );
    }

    private void sendUnavailable(HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE);
        resp.getWriter().append(
        // HTML document to show on 503 unavailable
        );
    }

    @Override
    public Wrapper getWrapper() {
        return wrapper;
    }

    @Override
    public void setWrapper(Wrapper wrapper) {
        // see also org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.setWrapper(Wrapper)
        if (null == wrapper) {
            return;
        }
        this.wrapper = wrapper;
        final Context context = (Context) wrapper.getParent();
        this.host = (Host) context.getParent();
    }
}
```